# Trouble implementing a simple algorithm for solving the DLP

Tags: number-theory

I have some trouble implementing a simple algorithm for solving the DLP in F_p^* using Mathematica.
The algoritm should look as follow:

```
p = RandomPrime[{10^2, 10^3}]
g = PrimitiveRoot[p]
h = Mod[RandomInteger[{10^2, 10^3}], p]

Naive = Function[{g, p, h}, 
  Module[{i, st, b, c, res}, st = 0; b = 1; c = Mod[h, p];
   For[i = -1, st == 0 && i < p - 1, i++, If[b == c, st = 1]; 
    b = Mod[b*g, p]];
   If[st == 0, res = "no solution", res = i];
   res]]
```

The only output I get is:

```
739
3
473

Function[{g, p, h}, Module[{i, st, b, c, res}, st = 0; 
  b = 1; 
  c = Mod[h, p]; 
  For[i = -1, st == 0 && i < p - 1, i++, If[b == c, st = 1]; 
   b = Mod[b g, p]]; 
  If[st == 0, res = "no solution", res = i]; res]]
```

How can I implement this correctly, so the DLP can be solved?

Comment: What is the DLP? Discrete Logarithm Problem? It would help to see a small example with input and desired output.

Comment: I guess your problem is you had defined a function, but you never call it to solve the problem. Does `Naive[g, p, h]` give you the result? (also it's best practices to not use names with a capital letter as the first letter)

Answer (score 1):

Your function dose not stop once the solution is found! So use a while loop and I suggest PowerMod, which should be more effective.

```
SolveDLP[g_, h_, p_] := Block[{j = 0},
   While[PowerMod[g, j, p] != h && j < p, j++];
   If[j < p, j, False]];
```

Testing this with your numbers gives

```
SolveDLP[3, 473, 739]
84
```